# Removing everything but emojis in javascript for google sheets script

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, google-sheets, emoji

Hey so I need to create a script using googlespreadsheets (javascript) that takes the input of one cell and outputs all the emojis from that cell into the selected one. I want to do this by removing everything from the cell text except the emoji. This is because if I try to just match emojis my output is not correct.

I'm using this regex to locate emojis.

```
  var re = /[\u1F60-\u1F64]|[\u2702-\u27B0]|[\u1F68-\u1F6C]|[\u1F30-\u1F70]|[\u2600-\u26ff]|[\uD83C-\uDBFF\uDC00-\uDFFF]+/gi;
```

How can I remove everything from the text except items with this regex. Or how can I remove everything but unicode. I have tried all the other suggestions but the output isn't correct or it doesn't work with spreadsheets.

Currently I have:

```
function SHOW_EMOJIS(s) {
   var re = /[\u1F60-\u1F64]|[\u2702-\u27B0]|[\u1F68-\u1F6C]|[\u1F30-\u1F70]|[\u2600-\u26ff]|[\uD83C-\uDBFF\uDC00-\uDFFF]+/gi;
   var result = s.match(re).toString();

   return result;
}
```

This returns all the emojis, but instead of seeing:  ⚠️❄️‍⚕️☃️ I see  ⚠,,❄,,⚕,☃, . The doctor is returned as two separate emoji-characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a custom function, Why not try the inbuilt REGEX?

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A5,"[[:print:]]","")
```

Emoji is not printable according to Google Re2

Comment: That worked exactly as I was hoping! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

To replace all emojis from `[A1]` please try:

`=REGEXREPLACE($A$1,"[©®‼⁉™ℹ↔-↙↩-↪⌚-⌛⌨⏏⏩-⏳⏸-⏺Ⓜ▪-▫▶◀◻-◾☀-☄☎☑☔-☕☘☝☠☢-☣☦☪☮-☯☸-☺♀♂♈-♓♟-♠♣♥-♦♨♻♾-♿⚒-⚗⚙⚛-⚜⚠-⚡⚧⚪-⚫⚰-⚱⚽-⚾⛄-⛅⛈⛎-⛏⛑⛓-⛔⛩-⛪⛰-⛵⛷-⛺⛽✂✅✈-✍✏✒✔✖✝✡✨✳-✴❄❇❌❎❓-❕❗❣-❤➕-➗➡➰➿⤴-⤵⬅-⬇⬛-⬜⭐⭕〰〽㊗㊙-----------------------------------------------#️⃣*️⃣0️⃣1️⃣2️⃣3️⃣4️⃣5️⃣6️⃣7️⃣8️⃣9️⃣]","")`

Related Answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70125203/5372400

---

`=REGEXREPLACE(A5,"[[:print:]]","")` is a nice solution, but have some drawbacks:

- it leaves these chars: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9   # * on the place of respective emojis 0️⃣ 1️⃣ 2️⃣ 3️⃣ 4️⃣ 5️⃣ 6️⃣ 7️⃣ 8️⃣ 9️⃣  #️⃣ *️⃣
- it also replaces other not printable chars.

[Test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iO7YjYWyfseQu_YCfRbGDPg7NskOgMu_iO1iGjr7KxY/edit#gid=308112842)