# Why google sheets save as PDF doesn't show emoji in Cell?

Tags: google-sheets

Do you know why some times the emoji icons show normal and some times show as just empty square in google sheets , also when I save sheet as PDF the icon show as line ! , can anyone advise the reason ? what should i do ?

Here is a link of the sheet ( ICON in B24 )
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LRmyNlKSQjADz0bG_-mDf6w0LqEg7IcPgVizXF4C-Xc/edit?usp=sharing

this is the link were i took the icon from .

https://emojipedia.org/emoji/%F0%9F%8C%9E/

Thanks,

Comment: @max-makhrov did you took the icons from the same [Site](https://emojipedia.org/emoji/%F0%9F%8C%9E/) Aboude-zoua "the Original Poster" took it from?

Comment: your sheet [example](https://i.imgur.com/N9FKStb.png)  is deleted if you can repost it?

Comment: I dont understand why the answers suggesting that there is no sloution get upvoted and yet my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73224033/19529694) works as expected get down voted >_< !

Answer (score 10):

### Why This is Impossible

Google Sheets does not export emoji to `.pdf` because it does not know what an emoji is. Google Sheets is able to display emoji when doing work not because Google Sheets itself can display emoji, but because your browser/operating system can. If everything was left only to Google Sheets, it wouldn't know how to display emoji at all.

The one exception to this is Noto Emoji (as already mentioned by [Max Makhrov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73221745/19361936)). Through [this page](https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=Test:%20%F0%9F%98%80&preview.text_type=custom&sort=alpha), it can be seen that no font built into Google Sheets has the ability to display emoji except Noto Emoji. Even then, Noto Emoji only displays it as a black-and-white outline. Every other font available in Google Sheets does not have support for emojis.

If Google Sheets allowed the addition of custom fonts, this would be fixable. However, it is currently not possible to add custom fonts into Google Sheets. There are additional "advanced" fonts hidden in the "Fonts Dropdown->More Fonts" menu (one of which is Noto Emoji), but adding truly custom fonts is not possible.

Perhaps a correctly built extension could fix this issue. Currently though, no such extension seems to exist. One Google Sheets add-on called *Free and New Font* purports to add this functionality, but it has absolutely abysmal reviews and demands some very dodgy permissions regarding one's Google account. I have not tested it, and have intentionally refrained from linking to it because it seems nearer to a virus than actual solution. I would not want anyone skimming this to get the wrong idea.

All of that leaves us with no way (except Noto Emoji) to have Google Sheets recognize emoji; therefore, there is no way to use the built-in Google Sheets "Export as PDF" functionality and have emoji be exported correctly.

### Alternatives

Since it is not possible to complete this task directly, I have provided some alternatives below.

##### Use Noto Emoji

Noto Emoji itself is the closest option Google Sheets has for exporting to `.pdf` which include emoji. The downside of this is that Noto Emoji only exports emoji as black-and-white outlines. If this is serviceable, Noto Emoji can be accessed by:

1. Selecting all cells with emoji in them.
2. Clicking the fonts dropdown menu.
3. Selecting "More Fonts" at the top of the list.
4. Searching for "Noto Emoji" and selecting it.
5. Pressing "OK"

##### Export Using Another Method

As [OSM suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73224033), exporting as an `.html` document instead of a `.pdf` would retain colored emoji correctly. Another program can then be used to convert the `.html` document into a `.pdf`. Similarly (with even more jankiness), a screenshot of the document could be taken, and the image added to a PDF later. If access to Excel is possible, Google Sheets supports exporting to `.xlsx`, and Excel has better support for exporting emojis into PDFs.

The downside of this solution is that it requires numerous additional steps that take place outside of Google Sheets. If this is serviceable, refer to [OSM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73224033) for steps to implement the `.html` solution, or Microsoft documentation for steps to implement the `.xlsx` solution.

##### Use Images Instead

Rather than using emoji, images could instead be used as [this answer by pjmg](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/132628) suggests. Using the `=IMAGE()` formula ([documentation here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en)), a picture of an emoji could be pulled from an outside source. Google Sheets would correctly export that image when a `.pdf` file is created.

The downside of this solution is that it is cumbersome to find sources for external images, the images are not true emoji (which will be evident when editing the document), and if the host of the image goes down, exporting will no longer function correctly. If this is serviceable:

1. Find a website that hosts images of emoji. [In this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/132628), jpmg suggests [iEmoji](https://www.iemoji.com/). The [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/) website would also work.
2. Right click the image and click "Open in New Tab".
3. Copy the link and put it into an `=IMAGE()` formula in the desired cell.

For example (courtesy of jpmg), if you wanted the "face with tears of joy" emoji, you could use `=IMAGE("https://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/face-with-tears-of-joy.png")` or `=IMAGE("https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/325/face-with-tears-of-joy_1f602.png")`

##### Create New Functionality

If none of the above solutions are serviceable, it's possible to request that Google update their software to fix the problem. Max Makhrov has already submitted a bug report [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241147770), which can be voted on to improve the chances that Google updates things. Though, it should be noted: I think that this is technically all intended functionality, so a feature request might be a better route.

Furthermore, if anyone is particularly motivated, creating a non-shady alternative to the add-on I previously mentioned could also be a solution. Ultimately though, I suspect this would be a very time-consuming task for little gain.

### Conclusion

It is not possible to use the built-in "Export as PDF" functionality in Google Sheets to get a resulting file with colored emoji. This is because there are no appropriate fonts available in Google Sheets. Workarounds exist, but none are optimal.

Comment: ***1) .xlsx, and Excel has better support! for exporting emojis! see [this](https://i.imgur.com/Iro78rp.png), *** 2) screenshot is not editable, ***3) Since he need one emoji in one cell i thought the image sloution is easy, Im stuck from yesterday :( its more challanging than it sounds.

Comment: @Osm 1) I do not currently have access to Excel so I cannot test my claim, but looking briefly online, Excel seems to have more options available for this type of work 2) Correct, they are not editable in the way `.html` is. At a very basic level, take a screenshot of the portion of the sheet which it is desired to export, paste that into a Google Doc, and export as PDF. Perhaps other non-Google programs make this more convenient. 3) From jpmg: `=IMAGE("https://s3.amazonaws.com/pix.iemoji.com/images/emoji/apple/ios-12/256/face-with-tears-of-joy.png")`

Comment: The most helpful answer so far appeared changing the font suggested first by @bobur-niyozov

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

You can print easily with few steps, *Colored and with any font*.

> **1** - Add a dot in the right bottom corner to indicate the edge
> and Go to File > Download > **Web Page (.html)**

[image]

---

> **2** - Open the webpage in your browser and print as a PDF

### Edit with Pdf editor

> **3** - Open the PDF file with **illustrator** or a PDF editor, delete the grid and columns and rows.

[image]

Print and Enjoy :)

Comment: @Aboudezoua in your case you need to insert 1 single icone per cell or multiple? alone or with text also in same cell.

Comment: only single icon in one cell .

Comment: As I require a scripting solution, this won't work for me. The most helpful answer so far appeared changing the font suggested by @bobur-niyozov

Comment: @MaxMakhrov  Print failed with Inconsolata and Sawarabi Mincho see [this](https://i.imgur.com/w8vw2OA.png)

Comment: Yes, thanks I know that. But the idea of changing a font was correct. And sinse there're tons of available fonts I have no proof that some other font will or will not work. I also believe that Google can fix this problem on their side. As I did not get any answer with some coding ideas to resilve it, I rely on Google devs to help.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov The Original poste dosent mention a scripting solution. i think your asking a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) .

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not mention it in the Bounty description. Here's an example of coding solution to print Sheet as PDF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088042/margins-parameters-for-google-spreadsheet-export-as-pdf. It was my mistake. But my problem seems to be with "Not possible" answer applied at most.

Comment: I would also post another question if I had at least a small hope to resolve this.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov In response to "And sinse there're tons of available fonts I have no proof that some other font will or will not work," please see [this website](https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=Test:%20%F0%9F%98%80&preview.text_type=custom&sort=alpha), which details every font available in Google Sheets. It can be seen that no font bar Noto Emoji can properly display emoji.

Comment: @SebastianSmiley I tested some. I plan on tasting them all. Until now, no font has given a desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Running into the same problem, and so far the only work-around I have discovered is to go to File > Download > Web Page and then print the resulting HTML file for that sheet.  You have to check the option in your browser's print dialogue to print background and images to get some of the formatting to print correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

### The original solution: change the font

if you don't have to choose exact font, emoji containing cells that are formatted with `Inconsolata` or `Sawarabi Mincho` fonts are perfectly exported to PDF.

---

UPD. It appears that these fonts export correctly only certain emojis like arrows, card signs, etc... while others popular emojis are not exported correctly.

### Notes

As [@Osm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19529694/osm) noted:

> failed with Inconsolata and Sawarabi Mincho see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySZ5L.png)

`Noto Emoji` seems to be the only font to work. Still Google has tons of fonts and we have no solid proof if some or any of them will work.

Chnaging the font seems to be the only [programmable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#setFontFamily(String)) solution at the moment.

---

[Vote the issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241147770) if you are effected.

Comment: I couldn't find the font , can you provide a working example please ?

Comment: @Aboudezoua failed with Inconsolata and Sawarabi Mincho see [this](https://i.imgur.com/w8vw2OA.png)

Comment: Hi Bobur Niyozov! `Noto Emoji` seems to be the only font to work. Thank you for the idea with changing the font. I'm still curious if you have a working example with other fonts too. Please share your sample Google Sheet and give a link that anyone can view.

Comment: uhh, sorry, it seem those fonts I noticed export only several emoji's only like arrows and gamecard signs. It my bad that I haven't tested with other emoji's. Yes, "Noto Emoji seems to be the only font to work for all emoji set"

Answer (score 1):

I've reported this as an issue here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241147770

Please wote the issue if you want Google to solve it.

---

Note: when I use fonr `Noto Emoji` emojis are printed, but they are not colored.

[image]

To use this font select 'More Fonts' option.

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets is now (as of ~28 April 2023) not even removing the emojis, it simply doesn't create a PDF. If using Google Apps Script to create the PDF, error code 500 is returned.

I've reported the bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/284486971

The only solution that works is removing emojis from Google Sheets before attempting to create the PDF.

This answer from @max-makhrov provides a formula for doing that https://stackoverflow.com/a/70125203/16465606

And here's some code for Google Apps Script to replace Emojis in text strings with blanks.

```js
/** remove emojis from text string */
const emojiRegEx = /\p{Extended_Pictographic}/ug;
const textstring = "I ❤️ emojis  but Google Sheets is not a fan.";
const cleantext  = textstring.replace(emojiRegEx,'');

console.log('emojis removed from text string: ',cleantext);
```

About the `replace()` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

**Emojis are considered to be special characters.**

So according to [this](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3371015?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop), if you want to insert a *special character*, it is recommended you follow the steps mentioned in there.

As for the reason why the PDF is not exported in the way you expect it - this is due to encoding since emojis are special characters. I suggest you insert the emoji as an image and only afterwards export the spreadsheet.

Comment: In google drawing, the export to PDF or PNG is not working for me even when inserting emojis as special characters.

Answer (score 0):

The Google status on this request is "Won't fix (Intended behavior)"

And many people cannot understand why a 1990s format like PDF is unable to accept Modern HTML Fonts. Generally PDF translators cannot physically support more exotic fonts like woof or csvg.

Commonly the html styles are

["Noto Color Emoji"](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji) (often via **Google** android **platform** apps)
["Apple Color Emoji"](https://github.com/samuelngs/apple-emoji-linux) (used on Apple platforms such as iOS and macOS)
["Segoe UI Emoji"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/segoe-ui-emoji) (as used by Windows platform in NotePad etc.)

These can be translated to monochromatic outline fonts for native use in older PDF standard Printout files. At best that may be two flat colours one for the fill and one for the edge. (Black & White is the most common combination.)

Here the source text is on left in windows 11 notepad, as inserted say on a keyboard.
Then we can see in windows 11 notepad (!argh !why two apps same name), what it would look like if on the web as HTML.
Then from that **print to PDF is on right** and its not same as source !argh !argh, why the differences

[image]
so for above the pdf shows

```
Title: try.txt - Notepad
PDF Producer: Microsoft: Print To PDF
PDF Version: 1.7
Fonts:
CIDFont+F1 (TrueType (CID); Identity-H; embedded)
CIDFont+F2 (TrueType (CID); Identity-H; embedded)
CIDFont+F3 (TrueType (CID); Identity-H; embedded)
CIDFont+F4 (TrueType (CID); Identity-H; embedded)
```

PDF has enough trouble using TTF monochromatic fonts as shown above [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0DxV.png] so google export fonts in the sample file are

```
 <office:font-face-decls><style:font-face style:name="Arial" svg:font-family="Arial" /><style:font-face style:name="Cambria" svg:font-family="Cambria" /><style:font-face style:name="Liberation Sans" svg:font-family="'Liberation Sans'" style:font-family-generic="swiss" style:font-pitch="variable" /><style:font-face style:name="DejaVu Sans" svg:font-family="'DejaVu Sans'" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable" /><style:font-face style:name="Linux Libertine G" svg:font-family="'Linux Libertine G'" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable" /></office:font-face-decls>
```

and the plain text is

<table:table-cell table:style-name="ce1" office:value-type="string"
calcext:value-type="string">text:p</text:p></table:table-cell>

***but on a web that is naturally colour enhanced*** since `lol` is considered naff however in any of the above fonts it would be a null character, or plain text in black and white.

[image]
[image]

For non font supported characters you could see Fonts: <#4> (Type3; embedded)

As explained by others simply export the html with html iconic characters and then ***print html to pdf*** where you can use the html emojis as plain text for find etc.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't mentioned:

You can using a pdf printer and it prints fine without the need to export to html first.

"Microsoft print to pdf" works.